# Python != operation vs "is not"

Tags: python, operators

In a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079786/caching-sitemaps-in-django), I saw a statement that recommended using

```
result is not None
```

vs

```
result != None
```

What is the difference? And why might one be recommended over the other?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why

Comment: Hmm. While the answer to both questions is the same concept, I think the upvotes and detailed answers here do contribute independently to the concept of identity and equality testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does comparing strings using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe)

Answer (score 374, accepted):

`==` is an **equality test**. It checks whether the right hand side and the left hand side are equal objects (according to their `__eq__` or `__cmp__` methods.)

`is` is an **identity test**. It checks whether the right hand side and the left hand side are the very same object. No methodcalls are done, objects can't influence the `is` operation.

You use `is` (and `is not`) for singletons, like `None`, where you don't care about objects that might want to pretend to be `None` or where you want to protect against objects breaking when being compared against `None`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - could you elaborate on situations when an object can break, being compared to None?

Comment: @viksit.  `None` has few methods and almost no attributes.  If your `__eq__` test expected a method or attribute, it might break.  `def __eq__( self, other ): return self.size == other.size`.  For example, will break if `other` happens to be `None`.

Comment: My favorite way to comprehend this is: Python's `is` is like Java's `==`. Python's `==` is like Java's `.equals()`. Of course this only helps if you know Java.

Comment: @MatrixFrog: In PHP or JavaScript we would say that `is` is like `===` (very equal), and conversely `is not` is like `!==` (not exactly equal).

Comment: Is `is not` a single operator or is it just negating the result of `is` internally like `not foo is bar`?

Comment: Great answer! To add on, an example of an object that would be break when being compared to None via an equality test would be the `dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta` object. When compared to `!= None`, it would return False, and when compared to `== None`, it would also return False. Weird, I know.

Comment: @Asad Moosvi
I was wondering the same thing, but we can check that `is not` is indeed a single operator: `False is not None # True` but `False is (not None) # False`

Answer (score 183):

First, let me go over a few terms. If you just want your question answered, scroll down to "Answering your question".

### Definitions

**Object identity**: When you create an object, you can assign it to a variable. You can then also assign it to another variable. And another.

```
>>> button = Button()
>>> cancel = button
>>> close = button
>>> dismiss = button
>>> print(cancel is close)
True
```

In this case, `cancel`, `close`, and `dismiss` all refer to the same object in memory. You only created one `Button` object, and all three variables refer to this one object. We say that `cancel`, `close`, and `dismiss` all refer to *identical* objects; that is, they refer to one single object.

**Object equality**: When you compare two objects, you usually don't care that it refers to the *exact* same object in memory. With object equality, you can define your own rules for how two objects compare. When you write `if a == b:`, you are essentially saying `if a.__eq__(b):`. This lets you define a `__eq__` method on `a` so that you can use your own comparison logic.

### Rationale for equality comparisons

**Rationale:** Two objects have the exact same data, but are not identical. (They are not the same object in memory.)
**Example:** Strings

```
>>> greeting = "It's a beautiful day in the neighbourhood."
>>> a = unicode(greeting)
>>> b = unicode(greeting)
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
```

*Note: I use unicode strings here because Python is smart enough to reuse regular strings without creating new ones in memory.*

Here, I have two unicode strings, `a` and `b`. They have the exact same content, but they are not the same object in memory. However, when we compare them, we want them to compare equal. What's happening here is that the unicode object has implemented the `__eq__` method.

```
class unicode(object):
    # ...

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if len(self) != len(other):
            return False

        for i, j in zip(self, other):
            if i != j:
                return False

        return True
```

*Note: `__eq__` on `unicode` is definitely implemented more efficiently than this.*

**Rationale:** Two objects have different data, but are considered the same object if some key data is the same.
**Example:** Most types of model data

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = Monitor()
>>> a.make = "Dell"
>>> a.model = "E770s"
>>> a.owner = "Bob Jones"
>>> a.warranty_expiration = datetime.date(2030, 12, 31)
>>> b = Monitor()
>>> b.make = "Dell"
>>> b.model = "E770s"
>>> b.owner = "Sam Johnson"
>>> b.warranty_expiration = datetime.date(2005, 8, 22)
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
```

Here, I have two Dell monitors, `a` and `b`. They have the same make and model. However, they neither have the same data nor are the same object in memory. However, when we compare them, we want them to compare equal. What's happening here is that the Monitor object implemented the `__eq__` method.

```
class Monitor(object):
    # ...

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.make == other.make and self.model == other.model
```

### Answering your question

When comparing to `None`, always use `is not`. None is a singleton in Python - there is only ever one instance of it in memory.

By comparing *identity*, this can be performed very quickly. Python checks whether the object you're referring to has the same memory address as the global None object - a very, very fast comparison of two numbers.

By comparing *equality*, Python has to look up whether your object has an `__eq__` method. If it does not, it examines each superclass looking for an `__eq__` method. If it finds one, Python calls it. This is especially bad if the `__eq__` method is slow and doesn't immediately return when it notices that the other object is `None`.

Did you not implement `__eq__`? Then Python will probably find the `__eq__` method on `object` and use that instead - which just checks for object identity anyway.

When comparing most other things in Python, you will be using `!=`.

Answer (score 51):

Consider the following:

```
class Bad(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

c = Bad()
c is None # False, equivalent to id(c) == id(None)
c == None # True, equivalent to c.__eq__(None)
```

Answer (score 25):

`None` is a singleton, and therefore identity comparison will always work, whereas an object can fake the equality comparison via `.__eq__()`.

Comment: Ah interesting! In which situations might one want to fake the equality comparison btw? I'm guessing this has security implications in some way.

Comment: It's not about faking equality, it's about *implementing* equality. There are lots of reasons to want to define how an object compares to another.

Comment: I would say it's more *confusion* implications than security implications.

Comment: I have not come up against a reason to fake equality against `None`, but incorrect behavior regarding `None` could occur as a side effect of implementing equality against other types. It's not so much security implications as it is just correctness implications.

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> () is ()
True

>>> 1 is 1
True

>>> (1,) == (1,)
True

>>> (1,) is (1,)
False

>>> a = (1,)
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
```

Some objects are [singletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), and thus `is` with them is equivalent to `==`.  Most are not.

Comment: Most of these only work by coincidence/implementation detail. `()` and `1` are not inherently singletons.

Comment: In the CPython implementation, the small integers (`-NSMALLNEGINTS <= n <= NSMALLPOSINTS`) and empty tuples *are* singletons.  Indeed it's not documented nor guaranteed, but it's unlikely to change.

Comment: It is how it is implemented, but it isn't meaningful or useful or educational.

Comment: And in particular, CPython is not the only Python implementation. Relying on behaviour that can vary across Python implementations would seem to generally be a Bad Idea™ to me.