# Is it better to use "is" or "==" for number comparison in Python?

Tags: python

Is it better to use the "is" operator or the "==" operator to compare two numbers in Python?

Examples:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a is 1
True
>>> a == 1
True
>>> a is 0
False
>>> a == 0
False
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why/1504742#1504742

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209755/python-operation-vs-is-not

Comment: Python 3.8 (still in development at the time of this comment) introduces a `SyntaxWarning` for using `is` or `is not` with a literal: https://bugs.python.org/issue34850

Comment: This question specifies **number**, but answers from 2008 (preceding this question), in the duplicate, already cover the question in relation to numbers, so the question is a duplicate. Also **Is it better to use** is asking for an opinion.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Use `==`.

Sometimes, on some python implementations, by coincidence, integers from -5 to 256 will work with `is` (in CPython implementations for instance). But don't rely on this or use it in real programs.

Comment: Classes that define `__int__` won't work properly with `==` either; they'd need to define `__eq__` or `__cmp__` :)

Comment: The reason for this being that Python automatically creates those integers prior to runtime rather than constructing them on the fly in order to save time, and thus these particular integers have ids before being needed in the program.

Comment: the `is` operator *works* with integers outside that range, but they just have different identities (as an implementation detail); also I thought the range was from `-5` not `-1`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I believe the range may have changed at least once, but I'm not certain about that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You're probably right, as it's not guaranteed, might be work an edit to expand a bit :)

Answer (score 33):

Others have answered your question, but I'll go into a little bit more detail:

Python's `is` compares identity - it asks the question "is this one thing actually the same object as this other thing" (similar to `==` in Java). So, there are some times when using `is` makes sense - the most common one being checking for `None`. Eg, `foo is None`. But, in general, it isn't what you want.

`==`, on the other hand, asks the question "is this one thing logically equivalent to this other thing". For example:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]
True
>>> [1, 2, 3] is [1, 2, 3]
False
```

And this is true because classes can define the method they use to test for equality:

```
>>> class AlwaysEqual(object):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return True
...
>>> always_equal = AlwaysEqual()
>>> always_equal == 42
True
>>> always_equal == None
True
```

But they *cannot* define the method used for testing identity (ie, they can't override `is`).

Comment: `is` is not exactly like Javascript's `===`, or at least not in relation to the question. For example, for me `2 ** 12 is 2 ** 12` is `False` (this is implementation dependent), but in Javascript `Math.pow(2, 12) === Math.pow(2, 12)` is `true`.

Answer (score 20):

```
>>> a = 255556
>>> a == 255556
True
>>> a is 255556
False
```

I think that should answer it ;-)

The reason is that some often-used objects, such as the booleans True and False, all 1-letter strings and short numbers are allocated once by the interpreter, and each variable containing that object refers to it. Other numbers and larger strings are allocated on demand. The 255556 for instance is allocated three times, every time a different object is created. And therefore, according to `is`, they are **not** the same.

Comment: The only safe use of `is` for comparisons is for the `None` object. And I suppose the `...` object.

Comment: `is` will work for all strings, not only 1-letter strings. This is referred to as string interning in the Python documentation.

Comment: @ujukatzel - Wrong. When I run `a = "this is one hell of a string"; b = "this is one hell of a string"; a is b` I get `False` as the result. Python (specifically CPython) only interns some small strings.

Comment: @Chris Lutz - Although the example you posted does return `True` to me, indeed you're right, it does fail for some bigger strings.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that (in CPython 1.5-3.7, at least), `255556 is 255556` _is_ true. That's because the compiler folds certain immutable constant values in the same compilation unit into a single value (as explained [on the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49472348/908494)). But your conclusion is the important part: Python is allowed to merge any two provably-immutable values it wants, and also allowed not to do so, and there's rarely any good reason to care about whether a particular implementation actually does so.

Comment: @ChrisLutz surely `is True` is valid as well?

Answer (score 8):

That will only work for small numbers and I'm guessing it's also implementation-dependent. Python uses the same object instance for small numbers (iirc <256), but this changes for bigger numbers.

```
>>> a = 2104214124
>>> b = 2104214124
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False
```

So you should always use `==` to compare numbers.

Answer (score 1):

== is what you want, "is" just happens to work on your examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 2 == 2.0
True
>>> 2 is 2.0
False
```

Use ==

Comment: It gets worse. `-9 is -9` is `False` in CPython!