# How do I make sure a value in a for loop is referring to a part of the list

Tags: python

I want to make sure that a value in a for loop is not only equal, but IS the same as another value.

```
x = [1,2,1,3]
for i in x:
    if i == x[0]:
        print("True") # I want to make sure this is the same as x[0] but I have repetitions in the list
```

I would like for True to be outputted only once.

Comment: `for ix, i in enumerate(x):` then `if ix == 0:` ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/how-to-access-the-index-value-in-a-for-loop

Comment: You'll struggle with numbers since [numbers up to 256 use the same reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2239737/1324033)

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to achieve? Why are those 1s supposed to be distinct?

Comment: are you looking to iterate starting at the second item in the list `for i in x[1:]` and/or are you looking to check `if i is x[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the `1` stored in `x[0]` and in `x[2]` are the same value. They are stored at the same memory address and are completely indistinguishable*. Instead, you can compare the *indices*, which are unique.

For example:

```py
x = [1,2,1,3]

for index in range(len(x)):
  value = x[index]

  if index == 0:
    print(value, "equals", x[0])
```

Or, preferably, using `enumerate`:

```py
x = [1,2,1,3]

for index, value in enumerate(x): 
  if index == 0:
    print(value, "equals", x[0])
```

* This is an implementation detail for CPython (the "default" implementation of Python). You can read about integer caching [here](https://realpython.com/lessons/small-integer-caching/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is` for reference equality (`i is x[0]`). That being said, `1` in most common Python implementation is always the same object, due to integer interning. For all intents and purposes, both 1's are the same thing.
You can instead differentiate by indexes, using enumerate:

```
x = [1,2,1,3]
for idx, i in enumerate(x):
    if idx == 0:
        print("True")
```