# Shorter way to check if a string is not isdigit()

Tags: python

For the sake of learning, is there a shorter way to do:
`if string.isdigit() == False :`

I tried:
`if !string.isdigit() :` and `if !(string.isdigit()) :` which both didn't work.

Comment: If `not string.isdigit()`.

Comment: @larsmans Why comment and not an answer?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: because this is so basic that I don't need rep from it.

Comment: @larsmans Nice point of view :)

Comment: @larsmans: hence the comment at the start of my post: for the sake of learning. I expected it to be something like this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Python's "not" operand is `not`, not `!`.

Python's "logical not" operand is `not`, not `!`.

Comment: But it's `not` my fault! In all seriousness, that's why I used the quotes, code notation and normal form to differentiate

Answer (score 15):

In  python, you use the `not` keyword instead of `!`:

```
if not string.isdigit():
    do_stuff()
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if not False:
    do_stuff()
```

i.e:

```
if True:
    do_stuff()
```

Also, from the [PEP 8 Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==.
>
> Yes:   if greeting:
>
> No:    if greeting == True
>
> Worse: if greeting is True:

Comment: (Off-topic: Anyone else thinks that `is True` is not *worse* than `== True`, but rather the other way around?)

Comment: @poke http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591125/is-it-safe-to-replace-with-is-to-compare-boolean-values

Answer (score 7):

```
if not my_str.isdigit()
```

Also, don't use `string` as a variable name as it is also the name of a widely used standard module.

Answer (score 5):

maybe using **.isalpha()** is an easier way...

so; instead of `if not my_str.isdigit()` you can try `if my_str.isalpha()`

it is the shorter way to check if a string is not digit

Answer (score 0):

string.isdigit(g) returns False if g is negative or float. 
I prefer using following function:

```
def is_digit(g):
    try:
        float(g)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The (!) only works when saying something does not equal something else (!=).

```
if str.isdigit() != True:
```

It doesn't make much sense to do it that way because you can just say equals True.

```
if str.isdigit() == False:
```

You could also just use *not* instead of (!).

```
if not str.isdigit():
```

Note: this will only work if the string is an integer, it will return false even if it is an integer written as a float (i.e. '1.0'). To check if a string is a number of any kind try this function...

```
def is_digit(str):     
   try:
      float(str)
   except ValueError:
      return False
   return True
```