# Remove highly correlated columns from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe name `data` whose correlation matrix I computed by using

```py
corr = data.corr()
```

If the correlation between two columns is greater than 0.75, I want to remove one of them from dataframe `data`. I tried some option

```py
raw =corr[(corr.abs()>0.75) & (corr.abs() < 1.0)]
```

but it did not help; I need column number from raw for which value is nonzero. Basically some python equivalent of the following R command (which uses the function `findCorrelation`).

```r
{hc=findCorrelation(corr,cutoff = 0.75)

hc = sort(hc)

data <- data[,-c(hc)]}
```

If anyone can help me to get command similar to above mention R command in python pandas, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 16):

Use `np.eye` to ignore the diagonal values and find all columns that have some value whose absolute value is greater than the threshold.  Use the logical negation as a mask for the index and columns.

---

**Your example**

```
m = ~(corr.mask(np.eye(len(corr), dtype=bool)).abs() > 0.75).any()

raw = corr.loc[m, m]
```

**Working example**

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
data = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10)),
    columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
data

   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
0  0  2  7  3  8  7  0  6  8  6
1  0  2  0  4  9  7  3  2  4  3
2  3  6  7  7  4  5  3  7  5  9
3  8  7  6  4  7  6  2  6  6  5
4  2  8  7  5  8  4  7  6  1  5
5  2  8  2  4  7  6  9  4  2  4
6  6  3  8  3  9  8  0  4  3  0
7  4  1  5  8  6  0  8  7  4  6
8  3  5  8  5  1  5  1  4  3  9
9  5  5  7  0  3  2  5  8  8  9
```

---

```
corr = data.corr()
corr

      A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
A  1.00  0.22  0.42 -0.12 -0.17 -0.16 -0.11  0.35  0.13 -0.06
B  0.22  1.00  0.10 -0.08 -0.18  0.07  0.33  0.12 -0.34  0.17
C  0.42  0.10  1.00 -0.08 -0.41 -0.12 -0.42  0.55  0.20  0.34
D -0.12 -0.08 -0.08  1.00 -0.05 -0.29  0.27  0.02 -0.45  0.11
E -0.17 -0.18 -0.41 -0.05  1.00  0.47  0.00 -0.38 -0.19 -0.86
F -0.16  0.07 -0.12 -0.29  0.47  1.00 -0.62 -0.67 -0.08 -0.54
G -0.11  0.33 -0.42  0.27  0.00 -0.62  1.00  0.22 -0.40  0.07
H  0.35  0.12  0.55  0.02 -0.38 -0.67  0.22  1.00  0.50  0.59
I  0.13 -0.34  0.20 -0.45 -0.19 -0.08 -0.40  0.50  1.00  0.40
J -0.06  0.17  0.34  0.11 -0.86 -0.54  0.07  0.59  0.40  1.00
```

---

```
m = ~(corr.mask(np.eye(len(corr), dtype=bool)).abs() > 0.5).any()
m

A     True
B     True
C    False
D     True
E    False
F    False
G    False
H    False
I     True
J    False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
raw = corr.loc[m, m]
raw

      A     B     D     I
A  1.00  0.22 -0.12  0.13
B  0.22  1.00 -0.08 -0.34
D -0.12 -0.08  1.00 -0.45
I  0.13 -0.34 -0.45  1.00
```

Comment: From the context of Machine Learning, one should remove all but one highly correlated columns. E.g. take columns "C" and "H". You should remove one of them, not both. I would appreciate it if you correct you code taking into account my comment.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov It's way to late but I wrote a function that implements R's `findCorrelation` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75379515/19123103) that removes all but one highly correlated columns. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44892279/19123103) works great but it removes all columns with correlation above the cutoff, which overdoes it compared to how `findCorrelation` behaves in R. Assuming these are features in a machine learning model, we need to drop columns just enough so that the pairwise correlation coefficients among the columns are less than some cutoff point (perhaps multicollinearity is a problem etc.). Dropping too many would potentially hurt whatever model that is built on this data. As [Sergey Bushmanov mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889508#comment88778596_44892279), between columns `C` and `H`, only one should be dropped.

###### Python implementation of R's [`caret::findCorrelation`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/topics/findCorrelation)

R's `caret::findCorrelation` looks at the mean absolute correlation of each variable and removes the variable with the largest mean absolute correlation for each pair of columns. The following function (named `findCorrelation`) implements the very same logic.

Depending on the size of the correlation matrix, `caret::findCorrelation` calls one of two functions: the fully vectorized `findCorrelation_fast` or the loopy `findCorrelation_exact` (you can call either regardless of dataframe size by using the `exact=` argument appropriately). The function below does the very same.

The only behavior different from `caret::findCorrelation` is that it returns a list of column names whereas `caret::findCorrelation` returns the index of the columns. I believe it's more natural to return column names which we can pass to `drop` later on.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def findCorrelation(corr, cutoff=0.9, exact=None):
    """
    This function is the Python implementation of the R function 
    `findCorrelation()`.
    
    Relies on numpy and pandas, so must have them pre-installed.
    
    It searches through a correlation matrix and returns a list of column names 
    to remove to reduce pairwise correlations.
    
    For the documentation of the R function, see 
    https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/topics/findCorrelation
    and for the source code of `findCorrelation()`, see
    https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/pkg/caret/R/findCorrelation.R
    
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Parameters:
    -----------
    corr: pandas dataframe.
        A correlation matrix as a pandas dataframe.
    cutoff: float, default: 0.9.
        A numeric value for the pairwise absolute correlation cutoff
    exact: bool, default: None
        A boolean value that determines whether the average correlations be 
        recomputed at each step
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Returns:
    --------
    list of column names
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Example:
    --------
    R1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'x1': [1.0, 0.86, 0.56, 0.32, 0.85],
        'x2': [0.86, 1.0, 0.01, 0.74, 0.32],
        'x3': [0.56, 0.01, 1.0, 0.65, 0.91],
        'x4': [0.32, 0.74, 0.65, 1.0, 0.36],
        'x5': [0.85, 0.32, 0.91, 0.36, 1.0]
    }, index=['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'])

    findCorrelation(R1, cutoff=0.6, exact=False)  # ['x4', 'x5', 'x1', 'x3']
    findCorrelation(R1, cutoff=0.6, exact=True)   # ['x1', 'x5', 'x4'] 
    """
    
    def _findCorrelation_fast(corr, avg, cutoff):

        combsAboveCutoff = corr.where(lambda x: (np.tril(x)==0) & (x > cutoff)).stack().index

        rowsToCheck = combsAboveCutoff.get_level_values(0)
        colsToCheck = combsAboveCutoff.get_level_values(1)

        msk = avg[colsToCheck] > avg[rowsToCheck].values
        deletecol = pd.unique(np.r_[colsToCheck[msk], rowsToCheck[~msk]]).tolist()

        return deletecol


    def _findCorrelation_exact(corr, avg, cutoff):

        x = corr.loc[(*[avg.sort_values(ascending=False).index]*2,)]

        if (x.dtypes.values[:, None] == ['int64', 'int32', 'int16', 'int8']).any():
            x = x.astype(float)

        x.values[(*[np.arange(len(x))]*2,)] = np.nan

        deletecol = []
        for ix, i in enumerate(x.columns[:-1]):
            for j in x.columns[ix+1:]:
                if x.loc[i, j] > cutoff:
                    if x[i].mean() > x[j].mean():
                        deletecol.append(i)
                        x.loc[i] = x[i] = np.nan
                    else:
                        deletecol.append(j)
                        x.loc[j] = x[j] = np.nan
        return deletecol

    
    if not np.allclose(corr, corr.T) or any(corr.columns!=corr.index):
        raise ValueError("correlation matrix is not symmetric.")
        
    acorr = corr.abs()
    avg = acorr.mean()
        
    if exact or exact is None and corr.shape[1]<100:
        return _findCorrelation_exact(acorr, avg, cutoff)
    else:
        return _findCorrelation_fast(acorr, avg, cutoff)
```

You can call `findCorrelation` to find the columns to drop and call `drop()` on the dataframe to drop those columns (exactly how you would use this function is R).

Using [piRSquared's setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44892279/19123103), it returns the following output.

```py
corr = df.corr()
hc = findCorrelation(corr, cutoff=0.5)
trimmed_df = df.drop(columns=hc)
```

[image: res]

Comment: Should line: if x[i].mean() > np.nanmean(x.drop(j)) actually be: if x[i].mean() > x[j].mean(). 

Seems odd to compare column i mean to "all that is outside column of j -which includes i itself".

I found this thread from github: https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/967

Comment: @RaimoHaikari thanks for letting me know about it. The open issue seems very convincing but it's weird that it's never been revisited. In the meantime, I did change my answer as you mentioned.