# Calling things from lists with variables

Tags: python

```
list = [yes, no, seven]

print ("What do you want to pull from  the list?")
answer = input()

print (list[answer])
```

How do i do this kind situation? I know this example doesnt work, but how does one make it so that it does work?

Edit: I would rather it be a number I input, 0 for yes, 1 for no and 2 for seven if that is possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete an item in a list if it exists? (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915920/how-to-delete-an-item-in-a-list-if-it-exists-python)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a `dict`, not a `list`.

```
my_dictionary = {'yes':1, 'no':4, 'seven':9}

answer = input("What do you want to pull from the dictionary? ")

print(my_dictionary[answer])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
list_ = [yes, no, seven]

print ("What do you want to pull from  the list?")
answer = input()

print (list_[list_.index(answer)])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, define the list of items properly:

```
>>> items = ['yes', 'no', 'seven']
```

Note that I call it `items`, because [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) is a built-in function.

Now get the input:

```
>>> answer = input("What do you want to pull from  the list? ")
```

At this point, `answer` is a string. But a number is needed for an index in the list of items, so it must be converted using the built-in [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function:

```
>>> index = int(answer)
```

Now you can print the item at the given index:

```
>>> print(items[index])
```