# Remove exact match word from the list

Tags: python

```
"I am a human"
```

From the above string I want to remove the letter "a" so that the string becomes:

```
"I am human"
```

I used the following code and it works perfectly fine.

```
plural = input("Enter a string: ")
processed = plural.split()

processed.remove("a")
```

However, if the sentence doesn't have "a" in it it ends up with an error.

```
"I am not an elephant"
```

In this case I want the program to ignore it. How do I do it?

Comment: What's the Error? Using Python 2?

Comment: `processed.remove("a") if "a" in processed`

Comment: You can use `if "a" in processed: processed.remove("a")`. Check this answer for more solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915920/how-to-delete-an-item-in-a-list-if-it-exists-python

Answer (score 2):

Its just a split on the text where the pattern matches. regex is much better to use though.

```
" ".join("I am a human".split(" a "))
```

OR

```
"I am a human".replace(" a "," ")
```

Comment: Answer that have only code and no explanation are not useful, please state what your code does and in what way it helps OP

Answer (score 1):

According to [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) the `remove()` method is raising an error when there is no such value in the list.

As you know that this might happend, you could just catch the exception:

```
try:
    processed.remove("a")       
except ValueError:
    pass # happens.
```

However it would be better to use regular expressions, for example [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

This won't break when something unexpected will be inputed in `plural`:

```
plural = "I am a human"
value = re.sub(' a ', ' ', plural) # Replace "space + 'a' letter + space" with one space
```