# Selenium search by tag name option

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webdriver

I'm trying to get all data from a website called Correios. On this website, I need to handle some dropdowns which I'm having some issues with, like:
It's returning a list with a bunch of empty strings.

```python
chrome_path = r"C:\\Users\\Gustavo\\Desktop\\geckodriver\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
lista_x = []
driver.get("http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/agencias/")
driver.maximize_window()

dropdownEstados = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="estadoAgencia"]""")

optEstados = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")

for valores in optEstados:
    print(valores.text.encode())
```

And what I get from that is:

```
b''
b'ACRE'
b'ALAGOAS'
b'AMAP\xc3\x81'
b'AMAZONAS'
b'BAHIA'
b'CEAR\xc3\x81'
b'DISTRITO FEDERAL'
b'ESP\xc3\x8dRITO SANTO'
b'GOI\xc3\x81S'
b'MARANH\xc3\x83O'
b'MINAS GERAIS'
b'MATO GROSSO DO SUL'
b'MATO GROSSO'
b'PAR\xc3\x81'
b'PARA\xc3\x8dBA'
b'PERNAMBUCO'
b'PIAU\xc3\x8d'
b'PARAN\xc3\x81'
b'RIO DE JANEIRO'
b'RIO GRANDE DO NORTE'
b'ROND\xc3\x94NIA'
b'RORAIMA'
b'RIO GRANDE DO SUL'
b'SANTA CATARINA'
b'SERGIPE'
b'S\xc3\x83O PAULO'
b'TOCANTINS'
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
```

How can I remove the empty b" "?

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915920/how-to-delete-an-item-in-a-list-if-it-exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right, you want to locate all these options:

[image]

Try this XPath expression to locate the dropdown elements:

```
//*[@id="estadoAgencia"]/option
```

The code sample:

```python
chrome_path = r"C:\\Users\\Gustavo\\Desktop\\geckodriver\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
lista_x = []
driver.get("http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/agencias/")
driver.maximize_window()

dropdownEstados = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='estadoAgencia']")

# Find elements in dropdown
optEstados = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='estadoAgencia']/option")

for valores in optEstados:
    print(valores.text.encode())
```

Via this XPath expression you will get all dropdown elements, without empty strings except one, which is in this dropdown. Output:

```
b''
b'ACRE'
b'ALAGOAS'
b'AMAP\xc3\x81'
b'AMAZONAS'
b'BAHIA'
b'CEAR\xc3\x81'
b'DISTRITO FEDERAL'
b'ESP\xc3\x8dRITO SANTO'
b'GOI\xc3\x81S'
b'MARANH\xc3\x83O'
b'MINAS GERAIS'
b'MATO GROSSO DO SUL'
b'MATO GROSSO'
b'PAR\xc3\x81'
b'PARA\xc3\x8dBA'
b'PERNAMBUCO'
b'PIAU\xc3\x8d'
b'PARAN\xc3\x81'
b'RIO DE JANEIRO'
b'RIO GRANDE DO NORTE'
b'ROND\xc3\x94NIA'
b'RORAIMA'
b'RIO GRANDE DO SUL'
b'SANTA CATARINA'
b'SERGIPE'
b'S\xc3\x83O PAULO'
b'TOCANTINS'
```

Note: the first element is an empty string because of this:

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

There is a small change required in your code:

```
 dropdownEstados = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="estadoAgencia"]""")
 optEstados = dropdownEstados.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")

  for valores in optEstados:
     print(valores.text.encode())
```

Comment: What did you change and *why*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51238583/edit), not here in comments (******** ***without*** ******** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the text from all the `<options>` of the *DropDown* with *id* as `estadoAgencia`, as it is a `<select>` tag it would be much easier and efficient to use the methods associated with `<select>` tag and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  estado_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('estadoAgencia'))
  for opt in estado_select.options:
      print(opt.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ACRE
  ALAGOAS
  AMAPÁ
  AMAZONAS
  BAHIA
  CEARÁ
  DISTRITO FEDERAL
  ESPÍRITO SANTO
  GOIÁS
  MARANHÃO
  MINAS GERAIS
  MATO GROSSO DO SUL
  MATO GROSSO
  PARÁ
  PARAÍBA
  PERNAMBUCO
  PIAUÍ
  PARANÁ
  RIO DE JANEIRO
  RIO GRANDE DO NORTE
  RONDÔNIA
  RORAIMA
  RIO GRANDE DO SUL
  SANTA CATARINA
  SERGIPE
  SÃO PAULO
  TOCANTINS
  ```

Comment: @GustavoMolina Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was useful to you for the benifit of the future readers.