# How do I get the first value from a list of keys in a concrete way in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

There is a dict (say `d`). `dict.get(key, None)` returns `None` if `key` doesn't exist in `d`.

**How do I get the first value (i.e., `d[key]` is not `None`) from a list of keys (some of them might not exist in `d`)?**

This post, [Pythonic way to avoid “if x: return x” statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117583/pythonic-way-to-avoid-if-x-return-x-statements), provides a concrete way.

```
for d in list_dicts:
    for key in keys:
        if key in d:
            print(d[key])
            break
```

I use **xor operator** to acheive it in one line, as demonstrated in,

```
# a list of dicts
list_dicts = [  {'level0' : (1, 2), 'col': '#ff310021'},
                {'level1' : (3, 4), 'col': '#ff310011'},
                {'level2' : (5, 6), 'col': '#ff312221'}]

# loop over the list of dicts dicts, extract the tuple value whose key is like level*
for d in list_dicts:
    t = d.get('level0', None) or d.get('level1', None) or d.get('level2', None)
    col = d['col']

    do_something(t, col)
```

It works. In this way, I just simply list all options (`level0` ~ `level3`). Is there a better way for a lot of keys (say, from `level0` to `level100`)， like list comprehensions?

Comment: @user3100115, I edited the question and referred the post you mentioned. I believe it is not duplicate. Pls check it again.

Comment: This question is basically a particular case of the original (duplicate) question, where the conditions are `d.get('level0', None)`, `d.get('level1', None)` and so on instead of `check_size()`, `check_color()`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
x, y = d.get('level0', None) or d.get('level1', None) or d.get('level2', None)
```

Is basically mapping a `list` of `['level0', 'level1', 'level2']` to `d.get` (`None` is already the default value; there's no need to explicitly state it in this case). Next, you want to choose the one that doesn't map to `None`, which is basically a filter. You can use the `map()` and `filter()` built-in functions (which are lazy generator-like objects in Python 3) and call `next()` to get the first match:

```
list_dicts = [  {'level0' : (1, 2), 'col': '#ff310021'},
                {'level1' : (3, 4), 'col': '#ff310011'},
                {'level2' : (5, 6), 'col': '#ff312221'}]
>>> l = 'level0', 'level1', 'level2'
>>> for d in list_dicts:
...     print(next(filter(None, map(d.get, l))))
...
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
```

Comment: Note that `filter(None, ...)` doesn't mean "filter out Nones". It means "filter out anything considered false when interpreted as a boolean".

Comment: @user2357112 - Yes. I think that is what's desired for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

There's no convenient builtin, but you could implement it easily enough:

```
def getfirst(d, keys):
    for key in keys:
        if key in d:
            return d[key]
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `next` with a comprehension:

```
# build list of keys
levels = [ 'level' + str(i) for i in range(3) ]

for d in list_dicts:
  level_key = next(k for k in levels if d.get(k))
  level = d[level_key]
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work on all Pythons:

```
# a list of dicts
list_dicts = [{'level0': (1, 2), 'col': '#ff310021'},
              {'level1': (3, 4), 'col': '#ff310011'},
              {'level2': (5, 6), 'col': '#ff312221'}]

# Prioritized (ordered) list of keys [level0, level99]
KEYS = ['level{}'.format(i) for i in range(100)]


# loop over the list of dicts dicts, extract the tuple value whose key is
# like level*
for d in list_dicts:
    try:
        k = next(k for k in KEYS if k in d)
        t = d[k]
        col = d['col']

        do_something(t, col)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a novelty item, here is a version that first computes a getter using functional composition.

```
if 'reduce' not in globals():
    from functools import reduce

list_dicts = [  {'level0' : (1, 2), 'col': '#ff310021'},
                {'level1' : (3, 4), 'col': '#ff310011'},
                {'level2' : (5, 6), 'col': '#ff312221'}]


levels = list(map('level{}'.format, range(3)))
getter = reduce(lambda f, key: lambda dct: dct.get(key, f(dct)), reversed(levels), lambda _: None)

print(list(map(getter, list_dicts)))

# [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```