# What's the pythonic way to chain if statements given n variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have the following function as part of a script [inspired by this](https://blog.ouseful.info/2016/12/29/simple-view-controls-for-pandas-dataframes-using-ipython-widgets/):

```
def view(a='', b='', c=''):
    if a=='All' and b=='All' and c=='All': return df 
    if a=='All' and c=='All' and b!='All': return df[(df['b']==b)]
    if a!='All' and c=='All' and b=='All': return df[(df['a']==a)]
    if a=='All' and c!='All' and b=='All': return df[(df['c']==c)]
    if a=='All' and c!='All' and b!='All': return df[(df['c']==c) & (df['b']==b)]                                                        
    if a!='All' and c=='All' and b!='All': return df[(df['a']==a) & (df['b']==b)]                                                                     
    if a!='All' and c!='All' and b=='All': return df[(df['a']==a) & (df['c']==c)]                                                                 
    return df[(df['a']==a) & (df['b']==b) & (df['c']==c)]
```

Is there a nice way to write all those chained if statements with a nice pythonic expression. Bonus answer if generalized for n variables.

**Note:** [Perhaps related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117583/pythonic-way-to-avoid-if-x-return-x-statements), but I still cant figure it out.

Comment: For the first line, you could write `a==b==c=='All'` or `all(lambda x: x == 'All', [a, b, c])`. I don't see enough of a pattern to generalize the rest though.

Comment: Also, since this is an "improve my code" request, this is really more appropriate for Code Review. Note though, that they require full, runnable chunks of code.

Comment: For the `df['a']==a` comparisons, is the `df` index always going to be the name of the variable it's comparing against?

Comment: @jwodder correct

Comment: I'd like to know a little about df.

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom a simple df with generic index and columns 'a', 'b' 'c'. I use this function as part of a script to filter the dataframe using a widget. 'a', 'b', 'c' are categorical variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is basically doing this:

```
if all parameters are 'All':
    return df
else:
    Take all the non-'All' parameters
    Test if each one is equal to df['name_of_parameter']
    Bitwise-AND them together
    Return df[result of previous line]
```

Let's start our rewrite by first taking a list of all non-'All' parameters:

```
notall = [x for x in [a,b,c] if x != 'All']
if not notall:
    return df
else:
    ???
```

Roadblock #1: We've now lost track of which value goes with which parameter.  Why do we need to know that?  So that we can compare the parameters against the correct elements of `df`.  We can fix this by storing not just the parameters' values but also their names in `notall`:

```
notall = [(x, name) for (x, name) in [(a, 'a'), (b, 'b'), (c, 'c')] if x != 'All']
if not notall:
    return df
else:
    ???
```

Writing out the name of each parameter twice is ugly, but it's either this or resorting to naughtiness with `locals` and/or `**kwargs`.

With that taken care of, the comparisons against the elements of `df` is easy:

```
 compared = [df[name] == x for (x, name) in notall]
```

Now, how do we AND them all together?  We could use [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`operator.and_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.and_), but (unless you've overloaded `==` to return a non-boolean, which I hope you didn't do), the elements of `compared` are all booleans, which means that combining them with bitwise AND is the same as combining them with logical AND, and Python already has a function for that: [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

```
return df[all(compared)]
```

Putting it all together:

```
def view(a='', b='', c=''):
    notall = [(x, name) for (x, name) in [(a, 'a'), (b, 'b'), (c, 'c')] if x != 'All']
    if not notall:
        return df
    else:
        compared = [df[name] == x for (x, name) in notall]
        return df[all(compared)]
```

or, even more compact:

```
def view(a='', b='', c=''):
    notall = [(x, name) for (x, name) in [(a, 'a'), (b, 'b'), (c, 'c')] if x != 'All']
    if not notall:
        return df
    else:
        return df[all(df[name] == x for (x, name) in notall)]
```

Now, about that naughtiness mentioned earlier: If all of the parameters are in a `dict`, then `notall` can just contain the keys, which will allow us to look up both the parameter values and `df` values without repeating ourselves (too much).  How do we get all the parameters in a `dict`?  With `**kwargs`:

```
def view(**kwargs):
    notall = [name for name in NAMES if kwargs.get(name, '') != 'All']
```

(Note the use of `get` to give the parameters their default values.)  But what should `NAMES` be?  It can't be `kwargs.keys()`, as that will only contain the parameters that the user passed in, which may not be all of them (and may even include keys we weren't expecting!).  Option 1 is to write out a list of the parameter names somewhere and use that:

```
NAMES = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Alternatively, if the keys of `df` happen to be the same as the desired names of the function's parameters, we can just use `df.keys()`:

```
    notall = [name for name in df.keys() if kwargs.get(name, '') != 'All']
```

or, slightly shorter:

```
    notall = [name for name in df if kwargs.get(name, '') != 'All']
```

After this, we just need to update how the elements of `notall` are used, changing this:

```
return df[all(df[name] == x for (x, name) in notall)]
```

to this:

```
return df[all(df[name] == kwargs.get(name, '') for name in notall)]
```

(Note that we still need to keep using `get` to set the default values.)

Putting it all back together again:

```
NAMES = ['a', 'b', 'c']
def view(**kwargs):
    notall = [name for name in NAMES if kwargs.get(name, '') != 'All']
    if not notall:
        return df
    else:
        return df[all(df[name] == kwargs.get(name, '') for name in notall)]
```

or, if the parameter names are the same as the keys of `df`:

```
def view(**kwargs):
    notall = [name for name in df if kwargs.get(name, '') != 'All']
    if not notall:
        return df
    else:
        return df[all(df[name] == kwargs.get(name, '') for name in notall)]
```

EDIT: Based on the comments below, apparently the values of `df` are something that overrides `==` so that it doesn't return a boolean.  Fortunately, as alluded to above, this just requires changing this:

```
return df[all(df[name] == kwargs.get(name, '') for name in notall)]
```

to this:

```
import functools
import operator

return functools.reduce(operator.and_, [df[name] == kwargs.get(name, '') for name in notall])
```

Comment: `df[all(compared)]` and its variants will just be `df[False]` or `df[True]`.  That doesn't seem equivalent to the OP's `df[(df['a']==a) & (df['b']==b) & (df['c']==c)]`.

Comment: `df["a"] == a` will be a bool Series, and bitwise anding a few of them together will give a Series which is then used as a mask.

Comment: @DSM: Where does the OP say that `df["a"] == a` is not a `bool`?

Comment: I'm confused about how the comparison returns a Series.  In my experience, it tends to be either True (they are equal) or False (they are not equal).  Similarly taking bitwise and of any python boolean values seems to result in a python boolean value.

Comment: @jwodder: unfort. you need to either know the OP's questions :-) or recognize df as the standard name for an arbitrary dataframe.  The OP confirms that it's a dataframe when he writes "[...] a simple df with generic index and columns 'a', 'b' 'c'. I use this function as part of a script to filter the dataframe using a widget. 'a', 'b', 'c' are categorical variables." in the comments.

Comment: @KennyOstrom: comparisons between scalars and numpy arrays or pandas Series return vector results.

Comment: So you should probably just delete this answer, because of stuff the question didn't mention originally.

Comment: @KennyOstrom: Harsh.  It's almost a one-line change.

Comment: Ah I see where you're going.  Since it overrides the operators, we just call them and let it do so.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
import itertools, functools
from operator import eq, ne, and_

def view(*args):
    Eq, Ne = functools.partial(eq, 'All'), functools.partial(ne, 'All')

     if all(Eq(var) for var in args):
         return df 

    for cond, ret in itertools.product((Eq, Ne), len(args)):
        if all(fun(var) for var, fun in zip(args, cond)):
            index = functools.reduce(and_, (df[var] == var for var, fun in cond if fun == Ne))
            return df[index]
```

The only problem is that there's no simple way I'm aware of to know the name of the variable you're currently using. This is why I used `df[var] == var`.

This is relatively easy to fix by making each variable carry its name with it, for example. So, basically, each variable'll be a tuple `a = (variable, "variable")`.