# Does a two parted condition with "and"/ && stop when one part is already false?

Tags: python, if-statement, runtime, conditional-statements

simplified example:

```
a = False
b = True

if a and b:
    #do stuff
```

Does python skip checking for b if a is already recognized as false because only one condition needs to be False for the whole statement to be False?

In my case i want to check an array for 3 conditions but want to stop if at least one of them is false (for a better runtime). Can i do

```
if a and b and c:
    #do stuff
```

or do i have to go the long way with

```
if a:
    if b:
        if c:
            return True
        else:
            return False
     else:
         return False
 else: 
     return False
```

or is there another way to check stuff like this?

Comment: It is just like how the truth table for your conditions would work.

Comment: Yes. See more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36551857/4014959)

Comment: On a related note, the `all` and `any` functions also short-circuit.

Comment: Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117583/pythonic-way-to-avoid-if-x-return-x-statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Python short-circuits.

Proof:

```
>>> int('ValueError')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ValueError'
>>> 
>>> False and int('ValueError')
False
>>> True or int('ValueError')
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you described above is called short circuiting and python does do that.

Similar is the case with `or` operation.

```
a or b
```

is short circuited at `a` if `a` is `True` otherwise `b` is checked.