# How to avoid "if" nesting when need Multiple return values in python

Tags: python

Like this,assume I need use some  library function(I can not change them),it return a value or None, I want use the returned value and pass it to another function.
How to avoid use many `if` statements at the same time?

Here is an example of my code:

```
import random
def somefunction1(n):
    m=random.randint(0,n)
    if m>5:
        return None
    else:
        return m

def somefunction2(n):
    # like somefunction1

# ------way one
r1=somefunction1(10)
r2=somefunction2(someParameter)
if r1:
    print(r1)
elif r2:
    print(r2)

# --------way two
r1=somefunction1(10)
if r1:
    print(r1)
else:
    r2=somefunction2(someparameter)
    if r2:
        print(r2)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly is your question? Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write a good question.

Comment: I am not good at english,the description may be a bit vague.The code is pseudo-code. I search,find [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36117603/12583761) this,but it can not use parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if r := somefunction1(10) or somefunction2(someParameter):
    print(r)
```

Comment: @krishna Woah, Python 8... welcome to the 21st, traveler :-)

Comment: Sorry, Python3.8 I mean to say.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, If you are not using out_put1 as input for another function then you can use like this.
If function1() return some value then out_put value will be that value.
else if function2() returns some value that then out_put will be value of function2() else it will be None

```
out_put =  function1() or function2()
if out_put:
    print(out_put)
```

Comment: Thank you, both this and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60693077/12583761) are good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def a_function(parameters):
    default_value = None

    apply_some_operation_on(parameters):
        if YouWantToReturnSomething:
            default_value = whatever_you_want_to_return

    return return_val
```