# In Python, does `is not int` ever return false?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argument parser to allow passing port number to my program. I then try to validate the value, and one of the first tests is the `is int` test:

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Provides XML-RPC API.')
    parser.add_argument('--port', dest='port', default=9666, type=int,
                       help='port to listen on, 9666 by default.');
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.port is not int:
        raise TypeError("Port must be integer (%s given), use -h argument to get help."%(type(args.port).__name__))
    if args.port>=65536 or args.port<=0:
        raise IndexError("Port must be lower than 65536, 65535 is the maximum port number. Also, port can only be positive, non-zero number. Use -h argument to get help.")
    if args.port<=1204:
        print("Notice: ports up to 1024 are reserved to well known services, using this port numbers often leads to conflicts. Use -h argument to get help.")
```

Now whatever I do, I get the error:

```
Port must be integer (int given), use -h argument to get help.
```

I mean, what the hell? Even the error says it was int, so what's going on?

Comment: Do you mean `isinstance(args.port, int)`

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2209781/3516028

Comment: Ah, thanks. I am beginner so I just misunderstood what `is` means.

Comment: Also "if it quacks, it's a duck!" aka duck typing. Consider you receive an `int` then catch exceptions if any is raised instead. It is more "Pythonic" that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`args.port is not int` will return `False` if `args.port` was ever set to the `int` type:

```
args.port = int
args.port is int  # True
```

or you re-bound `int` to the same object `args.port` already is bound to:

```
int = args.port
args.port is int  # True
```

That is because `is` tests if two references are pointing to the exact same object.

Perhaps you were confused on how to test for the type of an object, for that you use the [`isinstance()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance), or test the output of [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type):

```
type(args.port) is not int  # False if args.port is a different type
not isinstance(args.port, int)  # False if args.port is a different type and not a subclass either
```

This will never be the case either, because you configured your `ArgumentParser` option to only accept integers:

```
parser.add_argument('--port', dest='port', default=9666, type=int,
                   help='port to listen on, 9666 by default.')
```

The `type=int` argument is important, because that means that anything that cannot be interpreted as an integer will be rejected by the parser. You will never get past `parser.parse_args()` here:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Provides XML-RPC API.')
>>> parser.add_argument('--port', dest='port', default=9666, type=int,
...                     help='port to listen on, 9666 by default.')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--port'], dest='port', nargs=None, const=None, default=9666, type=<type 'int'>, choices=None, help='port to listen on, 9666 by default.', metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--port', 'not an integer'])
usage: [-h] [--port PORT]
: error: argument --port: invalid int value: 'not an integer'
```

That's because `'not an integer'` cannot be converted by the `int()` function; a `ValueError` is raised and `argparse` translates that to an error message for you:

```
>>> int('not an integer')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'not an integer'
```

You could supply your own conversation function that limits the range:

```
def portnumber(value):
    port = int(value)  # may raise ValueError
    if not 0 <= port <= 65536:
        raise ValueError('Not a valid port number')
    return port
```

Then use that as the `type`:

```
parser.add_argument('--port', dest='port', default=9666, type=portnumber,
                   help='port to listen on, 9666 by default.')
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, testing if something is an `int` is done by `isinstance(args.port, int)`. However, this check is not needed here since argparse will guarantee it to be an integer for you. If you had not specified a default, `None` would also have been a possibility, but this is not the case here since you did specify a default value.

Answer (score 1):

'int' refers to the class itself.  'is not int' would evaluate to False if you passed the class 'int' itself, which is not likely to happen. You probably want 'isinstance( args.port, int)' instead.

Answer (score 0):

`is not int` will always return `True` unless you do `int is not int`. This is because `is` is an identity test, which means that it checks whether the two arguments are the same object.

Let's say you try

```
>>> 1 is not int
```

This will return `True` because `1` is not the same object as `int`. We can check this more deeply.

```
>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>
```

As you can see `1` is indeed an `int`, but `int` itself is actually as class.

To fix this, you can just do

```
not isinstance(args.port, int)
```

as suggested by other answers.

You could also do

```
type(args.port) is not int
```

which checks if the type of `args.port` is `int`.