# Compare two boolean expression in python

Tags: python

```
In[19]: x = None
In[20]: y = "Something"
In[21]: x is None == y is None
Out[21]: False
In[22]: x is None != y is None ## What's going on here?
Out[22]: False
In[23]: id(x is None)
Out[23]: 505509720
In[24]: id(y is None)
Out[24]: 505509708
```

Why is Out[22] false? They have different ids, so it's not an identity  problem....

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209755/python-operation-vs-is-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x is None != y is None` is "[chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)". A more typical example is `3 < x < 9`. Which means the same as `(3 < x) and (x < 9)`. So in your case, with operators `is` and `!=`, that's this:

```
(x is None) and (None != y) and (y is None)
```

Which is false because `y is None` is false.

Answer (score 6):

Chained expressions are evaluated from left to right, besides, comparisons `is` and `!=` have the same precedence, so that your expression is evaluated as:

```
(x is None) and (None!= y) and (y is None)
#---True----|------True-----|--- False---|
#-----------True------------|
#------------------False-----------------|
```

To change the order of evaluation, you should put some parens:

```
>>> (x is None) != (y is None)
True
```

---

Also note that the first expression `x is None == y is None` was a fluke, or rather the red herring, as you'll get the same results if you place some parens in the required positions. It's probably why you assumed the order should start with the `is` first, then the `!=` in the second case.