# Pylint complains about comparing a string to a literal with 'is'

Tags: python, python-3.x, equality, pylint

Consider this code snippet:

```
my_string = 'asdf'
print(my_string is 'xfje') #R0123
```

Pylint returns a recommendation `R0123` on the second line, which I was unable to find on the [error message wiki](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com). There is a mention of it in [this part of the docs](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html), though:

> **literal-comparison (R0123):**
>
> Comparison to literal Used when comparing an object to a literal, which is usually what you do not want to do, since you can compare to a different literal than what was expected altogether.

This explanation is not helpful at all to me. I know that using `is` for comparison between two string objects may lead to different results than expected, but for comparison of object to literal, it is identical to `==` . And when using `==`, the error disappears.

Why should I not use `is` here?

Comment: Maybe you will find this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209755/python-operation-vs-is-not) more helpful.

Comment: "but for comparison of object to literal, it is identical to `==`" - where the heck did you get that idea?

Comment: @user2357112 I tried it in the prompt and it worked as I expected. But yeah, I didn't read any documentation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`is` checks that the left hand argument holds **the exact same reference** as the right hand argument. This is fine for `None` which is a singleton, but is usually a bad idea for other types, where multiple instances can have the same logical value.

Consider, e.g. the following example:

```
>>> my_string = ''.join([c for c in 'xfje'])
>>> print my_string
xfje
>>> print my_string == 'xfje'
True
>>> print my_string is 'xfje'
False
```

Comment: You shouldn't compare to `True` or `False`  using `is`. [Source](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) (last bullet point)

Comment: @Coal_ good point. Edited and removed those examples.

Comment: Daniel, I'm not entirely sure that is the case - checking `x is True` assures that `x` doesn't pass the check of `x == True` with `x = 1`

Comment: @MichaelGreen then you're not comparing `True` to `True` - You are comparing `1` to `True` which is different.

Comment: but `1 == True` evaluates to `True` in Python, which is my point; `bool` is a subclass of `int`