# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero even though I have a zero catcher

Tags: python, floating, integer-division, divide-by-zero

I'm a little new to Python. I have attached a snippet of code below. constant_a & b are integers. While running this code, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "U:\V10_run2\process.py",
>   line 209, in 
>       delta_mcs_2_gfx_percentage=(delta_mcs_2_gfx*100)/float(mcs) ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

```
mcs=hash["MCF"]*constant_a/constant_b  

if mcs is 0:
      delta__percentage=-100
else:
      delta__percentage=(delta*100)/mcs
```

As the error says I thought this was because python was trying to do a integer division & rounding mcs to 0 but I also tried `float(delta*100)/float(mcs)` which didn't help as well. Any suggestions ??

Comment: Is `mcs` a float or an int?

Comment: `delta_mcs_2_gfx_percentage=(delta_mcs_2_gfx*100)/float(mcs) ` doesn't appear in the code snippet you've provided us. The error message tells you where the error is happening, and it's not happening anywhere in that bit of code you've posted. Are you using an IDE with line numbers? Go to line 209.

Comment: stop using `is` except to compare to `None`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You don't need to use `is` to compare to `None`. This is Python, not SQL. Even though overusing `is` is a common mistake for beginners, that doesn't make it useless. Sometimes you actually do care about distinguishing between whether you're dealing with two equivalent objects or two references to the same object.

Comment: I heard it's "idiomatic" because `None` is a singleton. But `==` also works. You can code without `is` all your carreer. If you have to use `is` to test if it's the same object _in an operational program_, then you have a serious problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `==` instead of `is`:

```
a = 0.0

if a is 0:
    print("is zero")
else:
    print("not zero")
# 'not zero'

if a == 0:
    print("== zero")
else:
    print("not zero")
# '== zero'
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2209781/2799941) for a bit more explanation. Essentially, `==` tests for equality and `is` tests for exact object identity.

Comment: In CPython `0` should be cached though, so unless `mcs` is a float this doesn't explain his error.

Comment: `mcs` is a float in python 3 becuse it's the result of a division: `hash["MCF"]*constant_a/constant_b  `

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre OP didn't specify they were using Python 3.

Comment: but the message says: "float division by zero"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `1.0/0` will give you the same error.

Comment: okay. `mcs` is obviously a float, else `is 0` would work because 0 is in -5,256.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `is` when you should be using `==`.

`is` checks for the identical instances. IS this *thing* the same thing as this *other thing*

`==` checks for equality of the same or different instances. Is 0 EQUAL to 0.0?

My bet is that you are checking to see if 0 IS 0.0, which is it not. Then, when you divide by 0.0, you get the Error.