# Python code comparison with if validates False when it should be True

Tags: python, integer, comparison-operators

I have the following Python code below. I'm expecting the code to return `True` but when I run it, it seems to always return `False`. It seems to fail when checking if 361 is 361 but I can't work out why:

```
def comp(array1, array2):
    if array1 is None or array2 is None or len(array1) is 0 or len(array2) is 0 or len(array1) is not len(array2):
        return False

    aListSquared = [x * x for x in sorted(array1)]
    array2.sort()

    print(aListSquared)
    print(array2)

    for x in range(len(aListSquared)):
        print('{0}:{1}'.format(aListSquared[x], type(aListSquared[x])))
        print('{0}:{1}'.format(array2[x], type(array2[x])))

        if int(aListSquared[x]) is not int(array2[x]):
            return False

    return True


a1 = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
a2 = [11 * 11, 121 * 121, 144 * 144, 19 * 19, 161 * 161, 19 * 19, 144 * 144, 19 * 19]
print(comp(a1, a2))
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong or why the validation doesn't seem to be working correctly?

Many Thanks

Comment: As an aside, you can shorten up that first `if` leveraging the fact that `None` and an empty array are both falsey. `if not(array1 or array2) or (len(array1) != len(array2)):`. That clears up some the of the problems with `is` while you are at it

Comment: side note...just check for empty list or length of list for 0..meaning just do either `if not array1 or array2:` this implies checking for whether the list is empty or not so that way you can skip checking the `len(array1) or len(array2) is 0` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your lines

```
if array1 is None or array2 is None or len(array1) is 0 or len(array2) is 0 or len(array1) is not len(array2):
```

and

```
if int(aListSquared[x]) is not int(array2[x]):
```

you're using the `is` operator to compare two integers. That's not how the operator should be used in Python: The operator is to test for object identity, yet you only want to find out if the value is the same. In your case, you should just use `==` instead of `is` and `!=` instead of `is not` respectively.

For further reading, see the Python documentation on [Value comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) and [Identity comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not), as well as ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) for example.

Comment: As an example: `len(range(1000)) is len(range(1000)) == False`

Answer (score 2):

This syntax

```
if int(aListSquared[x]) is not int(array2[x]):
```

is not the same as

```
if int(aListSquared[x]) != int(array2[x]):
```

please refer to this [Python != operation vs "is not"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209755/python-operation-vs-is-not)

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting this expression:

if int(aListSquared[x]) is not int(array2[x]):
    return False

with this:

if int(aListSquared[x]) != int(array2[x]):
    return False

The code returns True.