# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'number'

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am using Flask to create a /register before call the /login page.

This error show when I submit my register and go to '/login'.

This is my 'app.py':

```
from projeto import app, db
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, request, url_for, flash, abort
from flask_login import login_user, login_required, logout_user
from projeto.models import User
from projeto.forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/welcome')
@login_required
def welcome_user():
    return render_template('welcome_user.html')


@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash('Logout realizado com sucesso!')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Grab the user from our User Models table
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()

        # Check that the user was supplied and the password is right
        # The verify_password method comes from the User object
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209755/python-operation-vs-is-not

        if user.check_password(form.password.data) and user is not None:
            #Log in the user

            login_user(user)
            flash('Login realizado com sucesso!')

            # If a user was trying to visit a page that requires a login
            # flask saves that URL as 'next'.
            next = request.args.get('next')

            # So let's now check if that next exists, otherwise we'll go to
            # the welcome page.
            if next == None or not next[0]=='/':
                next = url_for('welcome_user')

            return redirect(next)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User(name=form.name.data,
                    address=form.address.data,
                    number=form.number.data,
                    city=form.city.data,
                    state=form.state.data,
                    country_code=form.country_code.data,
                    phone=form.phone.data,
                    email=form.email.data,
                    username=form.username.data,
                    password=form.password.data)

        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Obrigado por seu registro! Agora você pode realizar o login.')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my '**init**.py'

```
import os
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager

#CREATE A LOGIN MANAGER OBJECT
login_manager = LoginManager()

#CREATE MY APPLICATION
app = Flask(__name__)

# CREATE MY DATABASE
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

#CONFIGURATE MY DATABASE WITH THE APP STRUCTURE
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app,db)

#Pass in our app to the login MANAGER
login_manager.init_app(app)

# Tell users what view to go when they need to login_manager
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
```

This is my 'models.py'

```
from projeto import db, login_manager
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    # Create a table in the db
    __tablename__ = 'usuario'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(70))
    address = db.Column(db.String(120))
    number = db.Column(db.Integer)
    city = db.Column(db.String(150))
    state = db.Column(db.String(20))
    country_code = db.Column(db.Integer)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(11))
    email =db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def __init__(self, name, address, numer, city, state, country_code, phone,
                email, username, password):

        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.number = number
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.country_code = country_code
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
```

This is the "Traceback"

```
    TypeError
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'number'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\Sony\_anaconda3\envs\rodrigovirtual\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\Sony\_anaconda3\envs\rodrigovirtual\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Sony\_anaconda3\envs\rodrigovirtual\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Sony\_anaconda3\envs\rodrigovirtual\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Sony\_anaconda3\envs\rodrigovirtual\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Sony\_anaconda3\envs\rodrigovirtual\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Sony\_anaconda3\envs\rodrigovirtual\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Sony\_anaconda3\envs\rodrigovirtual\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Sony\_anaconda3\envs\rodrigovirtual\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Sony\_anaconda3\envs\rodrigovirtual\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\Projeto_Flask\app.py", line 63, in register
user = User(name=form.name.data,
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'number'
```

I just wanna understand my problem to solve it.

I tried to search this problem, finding some cases, but still cannot figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Traceback would help

Comment: File "C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\Projeto_Flask\app.py", line 63, in register
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
Open an interactive python shell in this framedef register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User(name=form.name.data,
                    address=form.address.data,
                    number=form.number.data,
                    city=form.city.data,
                    state=form.state.data,
                    country_code=form.country_code.data,

Comment: This is still not the complete traceback

Comment: And you need to show us your models

Comment: I changed my question to show all of these, ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer.

You have a typo in your model's init method.

You wrote `numer` instead of `number`.

Answer (score 0):

Please, can you send the full error message, I'm mean the full exception. I'm think the problems occur from

```
               User(name=form.name.data,
                    address=form.address.data,
                    number=form.number.data,
                    city=form.city.data,
                    state=form.state.data,
                    country_code=form.country_code.data,
                    phone=form.phone.data,
                    email=form.email.data,
                    username=form.username.data,
                    password=form.password.data)
```

this part of code.

Comment: File "C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\Projeto_Flask\app.py", line 63, in register
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
Open an interactive python shell in this framedef register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User(name=form.name.data,
                    address=form.address.data,
                    number=form.number.data,
                    city=form.city.data,
                    state=form.state.data,
                    country_code=form.country_code.data,