# Difference between != and IF not in

Tags: python, string

can somebody please explain me the difference between if i use "if not ... in" or "!=" in my code

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
punctuation = ".,?'! "
message = "xuo jxuhu! jxyi yi qd unqcfbu ev q squiqh syfxuh. muhu oek qrbu je tusetu yj? y xefu ie! iudt cu q cuiiqwu rqsa myjx jxu iqcu evviuj!"
translated_message = ""
for letter in message:
    if letter != punctuation:
        letter_value = alphabet.find(letter)
        translated_message += alphabet[(letter_value + 10) % 26]
    else:
        translated_message += letter
print(translated_message)
```

output:

```
heyjtherejjthisjisjanjexamplejofjajcaesarjcipherjjwerejyoujablejtojdecodejitjjijhopejsojjsendjmejajmessagejbackjwithjthejsamejoffsetj
```

if i use "If not letter in message"

i get this as output:

```
hey there! this is an example of a caesar cipher. were you able to decode it? i hope so! send me a message back with the same offset!
```

Comment: `letter != punctuation` if `letter` and `punctuation` aren't identical — which is always the case in your code. `letter not in punctuation` if `letter` is not _contained_ in `punctuation`.

Comment: Good explanation here: [!= vs not in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209755/python-operation-vs-is-not)

Comment: @Shaddo That question is asking about an equality check vs. an identity check. OP's question is asking about an equality check vs. a membership check.

Comment: Btw, rather than use `alphabet.find`, you should create a dictionary of letters to numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOT IN search if the target element is another element :
"b" in "abc" should return True

!= or == compares the elements of the two sides of the equality and not their belonging :
"b" == "abc" should return False

```
for letter in message:
    translated_message += letter if letter in punctuation else alphabet[(alphabet.find(letter) + 10) % 26]
```

Answer (score 0):

**the `!=` means (Not equal to)
and `if not` means (Not equal to) also!**

there is no difference between them

Comment: There is a difference, though.

Comment: @OneCricketeer pls tell me what is it

Comment: These may result in the same **answer**, `"a" != "ab"` and `"a" not in "ab"`. But this does not mean they operate _the same way_. Also, question was asking about `not in`, not `if not`

Answer (score 0):

The **in** operator is used to determine whether or not a string is a substring of another string. (Same goes to not in)
For example,

```
if "tom" in "tomato":  
if "cat" in "catalogue":  
if "2" in "234":  
if "4" not in "890":  # or ... if not ("4" in "890")
```

And so on.
Similarly, **!=** operator is used to compare the values on either sides of them and decide the relation among them. **( a != b )** means
If values of two operands are not equal, then condition becomes true. So, it's not good to use this operator to check a particular string is included inside another string.