# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next' Error Code appears when Removing Nth Node From End of List using Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Right Now I'm trying my first medium leetcode problem for the first time (**Remove Nth Node From End of List**) and I'm pretty confident that the code I have should work with it. But for some reason when I it runs, my while-loop for `A.Next` gives the error:

```
NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def removeNthFromEnd(self, head: Optional[ListNode], n: int) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        a = head
        b = head
        c = head

        i = 0
        while i < n - 1:
            c = c.next
            i += 1

        while c.next != None:
            b = b.next
            c = c.next

        while a.next != b:
            a = a.next
            
        a.next = b.next
        b = None
    
        return head
```

It doesn't make sense as to why its not running because I defined my `a` variable to equal the head which should then also have access to `a.next` because again, its connected to the head. The `while c.next != None:` loop works fine without any issues so I don't understand whats causing the issue for my `a` variable.

Answer (score 0):

`head` is `Optional`, which means that it could be `None` when it is passed to the function. You should check if `head` is `None` first before assigning `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's going on. Your while loop checks a.next != b, which will never be true, hence a becomes equal to None eventually and the check a.next when a is None is failing with error mentioned above. This has nothing to do with linked list logic, it's simply how python compare things.

Your while loop

```
 while a.next != b: a = a.next
```

should be changed to

```
while a.next is not b: a = a.next
```

know the difference between != and `is not`, it's extremely important if you want to continue coding in python.

[Python != operation vs "is not"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209755/python-operation-vs-is-not)